# application of Fubini's Theorem

Tags: probability-theory

How could we use Fubini's theorem to prove 
$$\ E[Y-X] =  \int_{X<Y} \int_{X< t< Y} dt dP  - \int_{Y<X} \int_{Y< t< X} dt dP$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the integrated versions of deterministic identities: for every real numbers $x$ and $y$, 
$$
y-x=(y-x)^+-(x-y)^+,\qquad (y-x)^+=\mathbf 1_{x\lt y}\cdot\int_x^y\mathrm dt.
$$
Thus,
$$
y-x=\mathbf 1_{x\lt y}\cdot\int_x^y\mathrm dt-\mathbf 1_{y\lt x}\cdot\int_y^x\mathrm dt,
$$
which, integrated with respect to $\mathbb P_{(X,Y)}$, yields
$$
\mathbb E(Y-X)=\mathbb E\left(\mathbf 1_{X\lt Y}\cdot\int_X^Y\mathrm dt\right)-\mathbb E\left(\mathbf 1_{Y\lt X}\cdot\int_Y^X\mathrm dt\right).
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Use that for a random variable $Z$, you have
\[ E[Z] = \int_{\mathbb R} x \; dP_Z(x) \]
Now split this integral in two $\int_0^\infty$ and $\int_{-\infty}^0$ and write $x = \int_0^x \, dt$ for the positive Part. That should get you started.